# wildcard * not behaving in expected way in bash script

Tags: bash, unix, stdout, glob

I have a bash script as shown below. I run this in a directory containing files such as `input1.inp` and other files like `coords_i.xyz` and `submission.sub` in order to make some simple modifications to them:

```sh
#!/bin/bash 
sed -i -e '25d' *.inp
echo "*xyz -2 2" >> *.inp
sed -n '3,7p' *_i.xyz >> *.inp
echo "Q -1 0 0 3" >> *.inp
echo "Q +1 0 0 -3" >> *.inp
echo "*" >> *.inp
sed -i -e s/"replace1"/"replace2"/g *.sub
rm *.out
```

If I am in this directory, and I run all the commands individually in the terminal (line by line in the script), everything works fine. However, when I try to group all these commands into the script as shown above, I get an error - essentially after the line `sed -i -e '25d' *.inp`, the script stops and a file called `*.inp` is created in my directory. If I try to run the `echo` command separately after that, it says the command is ambiguous (presumably because of the existence of this `*.inp` file).

Why don't my wildcards work the same way in the script as they did when I ran them separately and sequentially in the terminal, and what can I do so that they work properly in the script?

Comment: How would `>> *.inp` work? A file descriptor can only be opened to one file at a time (even if you do `exec > >(tee one.inp two.inp)`, the FIFO writing to `tee` is only one descriptor). If you have _no_ matching files, the glob expands to itself (thus how you get your `*.inp` file); if you have *multiple* matching files, then it expands to multiple files and can no longer be used as a legitimate redirection destination.

Comment: ...anyhow, I would strongly (strongly!) suggest evaluating your glob only once, storing that result in an array, and then reading the array (or only the first element of the array, if you want to assert that there should only ever be one file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using wildcards this way is hazardous; the easy advice is "don't". Evaluate them only once, and then you can check their outputs before trying to use them.

In the below, we define an `assert_only_one` function that stops your script when an array -- assigned from a glob -- contains less or more than exactly one element. Consequently, we're able to write code that more clearly and explicitly describes our desired behavior.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob      # Stop *.xyz evaluating to '*.xyz' if no such files exist

assert_only_one() {
  local glob; glob=$1; shift
  case $# in
    0) echo "ERROR: No files matching $glob exist" >&2; exit 1;;
    1) return 0;;
    *) echo "ERROR: More than one file matching $glob exists:" >*2
       printf '  %q\n' "$@" >&2
       exit 1;;
  esac
}

inp_files=( *.inp );   assert_only_one '*.inp' "${inp_files[@]}"
sub_files=( *.sub );   assert_only_one '*.sub' "${sub_files[@]}"
xyz_files=( *_i.xyz )

sed -i -e '25d' "${inp_files[0]}"
{
  echo "*xyz -2 2"
  sed -n '3,7p' "${xyz_files[@]}"
  echo "Q -1 0 0 3"
  echo "Q +1 0 0 -3"
  echo "*"
} >>"${inp_files[0]}"
sed -i -e s/"replace1"/"replace2"/g -- "${sub_files[@]}"
rm -- *.out
```